# Where am i wrong in these two proofs? $\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C)=-(\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B +(\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C $

Tags: vectors, inner-products, outer-product

I want to prove $\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C)=-(\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B +(\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C $,here are my two proofs below

$\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C)=m\vec B+n\vec C$

$\vec A \cdot [\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C) ]=0=\vec A \cdot (m\vec B+n\vec C)$

$\vec A \cdot (m\vec B+n\vec C)=0=m(\vec A\cdot \vec B)+n(\vec A\cdot \vec C)$ , that is ,$m(\vec A\cdot \vec B)=-n(\vec A\cdot \vec C)$

Now here is the problem

**1**. If i assume $m=-(\vec A\cdot \vec C)$ and $n=(\vec A\cdot \vec B)$,it will become $-(\vec A\cdot \vec C)(\vec A\cdot \vec B)=-(\vec A\cdot \vec B)(\vec A\cdot \vec C)$,and it is equivalent

so i can say $\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C)=-(\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B +(\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C $

**2**. If i assume $m=(\vec A\cdot \vec C)$ and $n=-(\vec A\cdot \vec B)$,it will become $(\vec A\cdot \vec C)(\vec A\cdot \vec B)=(\vec A\cdot \vec B)(\vec A\cdot \vec C)$,and it is equivalent too

so i can say $\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C)=(\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B -(\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C $

However,$\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C)=-(\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B +(\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C \neq (\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B -(\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C $,so i want to ask where am i wrong?

Comment: You are not justified in making either of the two assumptions you make.

Comment: You are trying to prove the Grassmann identity. This should be straightforward by using index notation or by writing out those cross products and scalar products.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your equation in $m$ and $n$ is in 2 variables. But you only used one equation to solve for it, thats why we need another equation for it.

Since $m$ and $n$ are in ratio of those 2 dot products, the constant of proportionality can be taken out of equation. Say it is $q$, the equation becomes

$$
\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C)=q \space[(\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B -(\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C] \tag{1}
$$

Your expression in heading is just (1) with $q=-1$ . To get the value of $q$, we need another equation. A *not-so-elegent* way is to just put manual values of vectors for which we know the result. If we put $\vec A = \hat{i}$, $\vec B = \hat{j}$, $\vec C = \hat{i}$, we get
$\newcommand{\hi}{\hat{i}}$
$\newcommand{\hj}{\hat{j}}$
$\newcommand{\hk}{\hat{k}}$
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{i} \times (\hat{j} \times \hat{i}) &= q \space[(\hi \cdot \hi)\hj - (\hi \cdot \hj)\hi] \\
\hi \times (-\hk) &= q \space[\space\hj \space - 0 \space]\\
\hj&= q\hj \\
q &= 1
\end{align}
$$
Hence the result.

Comment: According to this: does OP not have a sign error in the title?

Comment: @KurtG. I don't think so.

Comment: OP writes $$\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C)=-(\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B +(\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C$$ while you prove $$\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C)=(\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B -(\vec A \cdot \vec B)\vec C\,.$$